# How can I get OpenApi-Generator to produce nullable DateTimeOffset?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

My API exposes some endpoints with `DateTime?` and others with `DateTimeOffset?`.

I want to generate an API Client using OpenApi-Generator, that will create client code for each endpoint, respecting the differences between the types.

OpenApi-Generator offers the option to `useDateTimeOffset=true`, which will generate the client using `DateTimeOffset` everywhere regardless of whether the API was exposing `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset`. As such, I don't want to use that.

So to resolve the requirement without that, I'm attempting to create a Filter in which I will specify that in the case of `DateTimeOffset?` the generator should use the type `DateTimeOffset` and make it `nullable`.

This is the Filter:

```
public class FixDateTimeOffsetTypeSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema model, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.Type == typeof(DateTimeOffset?))
        {
            model.Format = "date-time-offset-nullable";
            model.Type = "DateTimeOffset"; 
            model.Nullable = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is an example of the output from that:

```
"/Api/MyApiEndpoint": {
  "get": {
    "tags": [
      "General"
    ],
    "operationId": "General_MyApiEndpoint",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "startDatetime",
        "in": "query",
        "schema": {
          "type": "DateTimeOffset",
          "format": "date-time-offset-nullable",
          "nullable": true
        }
      },
```

When I run this and generate the client from that JSON, the the `DateTimeOffset` objects are never `nullable`. It doesn't seem to respect that instruction.

What do I need to change to make it work, so that when I specify `DateTimeOffset` should be `nullable`, it appears as `nullable` in the code?

Comment: In which language, are you generating the client

Comment: How about `parameters - $ref: '#/components/parameters/DateTimeOffset'` and defining all in the parameter definition?

Comment: Also, which OpenApi version is that one?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a known problem:
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/3530

And here is the pull request that solves it: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/3530/commits/89fd5d70e9f15a5be9ffe26c2beddc07770043c0

Also check this link: https://jane.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips/nullable.html

Comment: For 300 points I'd like a more comprehensive answer than just links

Comment: It is hard to answer something certain without knowing the open API generator version. 
If the version is <4.1.0 - updating it should resolve it. If updating is not possible - you can still patch it.
Syntax also differs depending on the version. Which version are you using?